# Why was Ulysse the first human to speak?

Tags: novel, planet-of-the-apes, post-apocalyptic

In Pierre Boulle's novel *[Planet of the Apes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes_%28novel%29)* (aka *Monkey Planet*), Humans had been used as Ape slaves and exposed to their speech for generations, possibly since the long distant Ape apocalypse. Speech between the species should have been a common, ongoing thing. Did Boulle explain why Ulysse was the first human known to speak?

Answer (score 3):

Humans living on the planet has lost their civilisation and culture long ago.  They have been living as an animal and were not speaknig.

Ulysse and the other human protagonists of the novel has just arrived to the planet in a spaceship at the beginning of the novel.

Comment: I can see why the wild humans may have lost the ability to speak, but why did the human slaves remain speechless?

Comment: @Major: the humans lost their civilisation before the apes' civilisation has risen.  It's a plot point in the book that the apes didn't even know about the earlier human civilisation.